# Delete columns when a specific value is entered in cell (in another tab)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a tab where I enter a certain number (between 1 and 20) in a cell. When I type the number, I would like to automatically delete columns in another tab.

The next tab has a table with 20 columns. If I enter the number 1 in the cell in tab 1, I want to automatically delete columns 2 to 20 in tab 2.

I don't want to run the macro manually but rather automate the deleting process when the value is entered.

Would something that starts like this work?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
        If Target.Value = 1 Then Columns("B:T").Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

I would put the code directly in Sheet 1, where I enter the value (in Cell B2 let's say). Then if I enter the 1 value it would delete columns B to T (2 to 19).

I would need to reference sheet 2 to delete the columns.

Should I then keep adding If statement for values 2, 3, 4, ... to 20 and change my columns delete statement?

Screenshot of the table:
[image]

Columns C to V will be deleted or added based on the number I input in another sheet, column X will be sum of numbers indicated on the line (from column C to V). Column Z has a formula that is linked to another sheet (empty for now hence 0) and Column AB is dividing Column X by Column Z.

Comment: Take a look at the [`Worksheet.Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event. Very doable.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question with the beginning of a code.

Comment: So you only want to keep the column number that is placed into B2?

Comment: Are you working with a table that is actually formatted as a table (Ctrl+T)?

Comment: @urdearboy: Actually no, it's the column that are less or equal to the number I put. The number in B2 will indicate the number of projects, and then in Sheet I want to keep a column for all the projects, If I put 5, then I should have 5 columns for each of the projects.

Comment: @BigBen: I didn't create the original document, but when I go to the Data Manager I don't see the list of tables, so I don't think they were formatted as Tables, but just created with formulas in them

Answer (score 0):

This method makes use of a loop. This assumed your second sheet name is `Sheet2`, you have 20 columns, AND your table starts at `Column A`.

You may need to make this more systematic - this will work fine the first time it is used but once you delete a column, you will shift the entire range. You may also want to add a prompt to verify selection. What if butter fingers hits 3 instead of 2? You will delete the column and you cannot use  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>Z</kbd>  in VBA... just some thoughts

---

1. Make sure the changed cell is `B2` before doing anything
2. Make sure the input to `B2` is actually a number. Here the macro is limited to numbers between 1 - 20
3. Loop through your columns and delete any column index # that is not equal to `B2` value

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") '<-- Sheet with table
Dim i As Long

Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target > 0 And Target < 21 Then
            For i = 1 To 20

                If Target <> i Then
                    ws.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
                End If

            Next i
        End If
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @urdearboy, you actually make some good points: 1 - The sheet name will be different, but that's no issue. 2 - It won't be starting in column A (there are different ranges I will delete, but i wanted to ask a simple question to start from). 3 - The most important think i didn't mention, is that i want it to be reversible, in a sense that if i press 3, it keeps the first 3 columns, and then if I modify to 5, it adds back up two more columns. If that makes sense

Comment: Maybe you should only hide the columns then. Then it can be undone and you never change the range you are looping through.

Comment: Ideally, that is was I wanted to do, but the person who did the original excel document put a lot of formulas in cells on other tabs, and if I leave a project column that is not used, then it will create div#0 everywhere. Otherwise I was thinking of using the data manager to make the formulas implicit and avoid this. Which would allow to hide unused columns without having all this dependency.